# Error when trying to define Functional (SAM) interfaces

Tags: android, kotlin, syntax, functional-interface

In Kotlin, i'm trying to define an Interface with only one method.
When trying to the following code:

```
  fun interface someInterFace
{
    fun someFunc()
}
```

I'm getting the following error message:
"expecting function name or receiver type"
Can someone explain me what i'm doing wrong?
I'm using it exactly as it described in:
[Functional (SAM) interfaces](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/fun-interfaces.html)

Comment: Which version of kotlin you are targeting? SAM for fun interfaces are available only after 1.4+

Comment: Just to confirm that you are using Kotlin 1.4?

Comment: buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
 
    }

Comment: You need to use Kotlin 1.4 - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew14.html#sam-conversions-for-kotlin-interfaces

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew14.html#sam-conversions-for-kotlin-interfaces

Comment: I have changed the ext.kotlin_version to 1.4+ and i still have the same problem

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the languageVersion of kotlin to 1.4 or above that. For that, you do not have to change the version of ext.kotlin_version to 1.4+, but You need to write just a few lines in build.gradle file:

```
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
    languageVersion = "1.4"
}
```

You can now sync the gradle and your code will work now.